# Bayesian networks with CPT's defined by data and experts

Tags: r, machine-learning, bayesian-networks

I'm trying to create a Bayesian network in R, which combines defining conditional probability tables (CPT's) learnt from data and those defined by an expert.

I can create Bayesian networks that use CPT's defined by me or learnt from data, but not ones that combine both. I used bn.fit to train my Bayesian network from data.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I've come up with a work around. I've taught part of my Bayesian network using bn.fit. I've then constructed the full Bayesian network manually, defining the CPT's for the nodes that bn.fit learnt across, using the CPT's that bn.fit came up with. I then defined the rest manually. Surely there must be a built in method for doing this.